# regex to match graphic characters like smileys or word characters from multiple languages

Tags: python, regex, twitter, locale

I've a bunch of tweets from multiple languages and containing lots of smileys and other graphical unicode code points. I'd like to be able to tokenize these texts so that the graphical characters are separate tokens (to do this, I could for example, surround them by spaces and then split on white space).

Here's an example of a potential tweet text using the following glyphs:

FACE SCREAMING IN FEAR:  (U+1F631)

KISS MARK:  (U+1F48B)

```
# glyph_re is the regular expression I'm looking for
tw = u"piñata\U0001f631 \U0001f48bčíslo"
tw_spaced = re.sub(u'('+glyph_re+u')',ur' \1 ',tw)
tw_tokens = re.split(ur'\s',tw_spaced)
desired output = [u"piñata",u"\U0001f631",u"\U0001f48b",u"číslo"]
```

I'd like `glyph_re` to capture any character that isn't white space or used in the script of some language. In this example, `piñata` is Spanish and `číslo` is Czech. I tried using `ur"[^\w\s]"` and adding `flags=re.U` to the `sub` and `split` calls, but it seems the glyphs are seen as word characters, at least in Ubuntu and OSX (in which language, I'd like to know!).

Comment: could you provide an example along with expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I added an example. I'm currently thinking the best way may be to identify which code points are used for smileys and other pictures, and search for that range...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic trouble is that the default `re` package (in python 2.7 at any rate) does not handle unicode very well. There is, however, a revamped regular expression [package on pypi called `regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that does a better job.

The regex package readme states:

> 'The LOCALE flag is intended for legacy code and has limited support. You're still recommended to use Unicode instead.'

With the regex package, you can refer to unicode properties with the `\p{...}` and negated `\P{...}` constructs. So to find strings of 'letters' from any language, you can use:

```
reWords = '\p{Letter}+'
```

The official unicode website has a list of some useful [general character properties](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values).

To achieve the tokenisation I mention in the question, I did this:

```
import regex as re

def tokenize(s):
    words,glyphs = [],[]
    for part in re.split(ur'\P{Letter}+',s):
        if part:
            words.append(part)
    for part in re.split(ur'(\p{Letter}|\p{Separator})+',s)[0::2]:
        glyphs.extend(unicodeCharIterator(part))
    return words,glyphs

s=ur"piñata\U0001f631 \U0001f48bčíslo"
words,glyphs = tokenize(s)
```

It's the order of the words/glyphs is lost, but for my purposes that isn't important.

I've used `General_Category` values, but there's also other character properties like `Script` (if it's an empty string, it doesn't belong to the script of any language) and `Alphabetic` (a binary propoerty) that could be used. Wikipedia has a [page on unicode character properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property).